# RVM keeps on resetting/uninstalling gems every time I switch to different gemsets, how can I fix this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems, rvm

I notice that everytime I switch gemsets I have to run bundle install. I never had to do this before. What could be the problem?

Also rvm use 1.9.3-p0@name_of is the correct command to be using right?

I have this set in an .rvmrc file for each directory for my apps.

Comment: please include `rvm info` before and after switching gemsets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .rvmrc you just specify what are you will be use:

```
rvm 1.9.3-p0@name_of
```

And when you want to use this specific gemset just:

```
rvm use 1.9.3-p0@name_of
```

Or even better create and alias for your project!!!

```
rvm alias create project_name 1.9.3-p0@name_of
```

and after, when you will use the gemset just type:

```
rvm use project_name
```

Hope you find this helpful!